# So im new in programming how do i make the gender M and F to make them lower case and upper

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GenderGame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String gender, fName, lName, married;
    int age;
 
   System.out.print("What is your gender (M or F): ");
    gender = keyboard.next(); 
    
    System.out.print("First Name: ");
    fName = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Last Name: ");
    lName = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Age: ");
    age = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    
    if (gender.equals("F") && age >= 20) {
    
      System.out.print("Are you married, " + fName + " (y or n)? ");
      married = keyboard.next();
      System.out.println();

      if (married.equals("y")) {
        System.out.println("Then I shall call you Mrs. " + lName + ".");
      }
    
    
      if (married.equals("n")) {
        System.out.println("Then I shall call you Ms. " + lName + ".");
      }
    }

    if (age < 20) {
      System.out.println("Then I shall call you " + fName + " " + lName);
    }

    if (gender.equals("M") && age >= 20) {
      System.out.println("Then I shall call you Mr. " + lName + ".");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What exactly are you trying to make uppercase or lowercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare Strings without caring for upper or lower case.

For example:

```
if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F") && age >= 20) {
    // your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To lowercase

```
String lowercaseGender = gender.toLowerCase()
```

To uppercase

```
String uppercaseGender = gender.toUpperCase()
```

If you want to ignore the case and check equality you can do the below,

```
gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could uppercase the gender input before comparing it:

```java
if ("F".equals(gender.toUpperCase()) && age >= 20) {
    // your logic here ...
```

Side note: Please compare the string constant `"F"` on the LHS to the gender string variable on the RHS, not vice-versa.  Doing the comparison this way avoids a null pointer exception should the gender happen to be null.